# How to solve "Failed to connect to MySQL Host" Error in CentOS

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, connection, host

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Host 'IP-Address' is not allowed to
>   connect to this MySQL server.

CentOS server is our MySql host server and i want to connect that mysql from another client web-host server.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add user for the host to your mysql side and write below command.

```
mysql -p,
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DB_NAME.* TO USER@HOST_IP IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

note: your port must be 3306

Answer (score 1):

Try to see iptables and check that you're allowed to connect to server from your host, allow port 3306

Add user for the host your mysql side:
`mysql -p,
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_database.* TO your_user@ip_of_your_host IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mysql -p GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DB_NAME.* TO USER@HOST_IP IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

I use this twice in last month.